# Samsung Galaxy S2 boot loop

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, rooting, boot-loop

Today I updated my S2 with the android version provided by the carrier, but I thought it went wrong because of the lack of space on /storage and afterwords some of the apps lost their settings. Also after the update all the apps started to have disk space errors when trying to update, so I deleted some of the apps or moved them to external sd, but still had little space on the 2Gb partition.
I looked for a rooting solution and since I'm on Ubuntu I downloaded Heimdall.
I downloaded the latest firmware version for I9100 from sammobile.com and in console I ran the following command (saw this in a tutorial)

```
sudo heimdall flash --factoryfs factoryfs.img
```

And I got this error

```
Uploading FACTORYFS
21%
ERROR: Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!
FACTORYFS upload failed!
Ending session...
Rebooting device...
Re-attaching kernel driver...
```

Now everytime I try to boot my phone it goes into recovery mode.

How can I get pass the booting sequence and install a new and functional android rooted version? Am I missing something in the process, is my first attempt to root my phone.